# React RefObject as Array in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have problem with get values from reference object in array. Get data from reducer -> each on collection -> get values from input

When entering to component reference return empty array, but when I save something in code the reference working.

Can anyone help me? I am a beginner with React and Typescript and someone can explain me what I doing wrong.

Some code

```js
interface StorableCreateProps extends RouteComponentProps<MatchParams> {
    containers: Container[],
    getContainers: () => void
    addStorables: (locations: Array<string>, storables: Object[]) => void
}

type StorableCreateState = {
    storablesCount: Array<any>,
    open: boolean
}

class StorableCreate extends React.Component<StorableCreateProps, StorableCreateState> {
    containerCount: React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>[] = this.props.containers.map(() =>       React.createRef());
    
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.getContainers()
    }
    

    render() {
        console.log(this.containerCount.map(el => el.current));
        return (
            <div>
                <Card variant="outlined">
                    <CardContent>
                        <Box>
                            {
                                this.props.containers.map((row, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div key={index}>
                                            <ContainerStorable ref={this.containerCount[index]} container={row} />
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </Box>
                    </CardContent>
                </Card>
            </div>
        )
    }
  }
  
  type ContainerStorableProps = {
    container: Container,
}
export const ContainerStorable = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, ContainerStorableProps>((props, ref) => {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState<string>("0");

    return (
        <div>
            <Grid container spacing={4} justify="center">
                <Grid item md={4}>
                    <Typography variant="body1">{props.container.container_name}</Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={2}>
                    <Typography variant="body1">{props.container.short_name}</Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={1}>
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        placeholder="0"
                        size="small"
                        label="Count"
                        value={count}
                        inputRef={ref}
                        variant="outlined"
                        onChange={(e) => setCount(e.target.value)}
                        name={props.container.id.toString()}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item md={2}>
                    <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        className="btn-success"
                        style={{ borderRadius: '50%', width: 40, height: 40, minWidth: 0 }}
                    >
                        <Add />
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think you need to be using refs here.  If you want to access the count for each container from the `StorableCreate`, then what you should do is keep your state in `StorableCreate`.  The state would be an array of counts or of container props.  Each `ContainerStorable` would get a `count` and `setCount` as props.  But to be honest I am not really sure what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for tip. It is working. The question is for close